# Create an array from the data grabbed from the url

Tags: java, arrays, url

Hi so im a complete noob with this but using some tutorials etc i have some code that will grab the data from the url and output it in the console separated by commas. I want to store these into an array so i can output one specific value later on. Many thanks

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL oracle = new URL("http://http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=peckishwhale");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
}
```

The above code outputs the following

```
827,2111,227033174 18873,99,13149102 19093,99,13186202 2423,99,21576563 2625,99,27614813 882,99,23216231 8038,85,3258842 361,99,21122150 20817,98,12039891 10787,90,5600042 20728,94,8243999 8270,91,6089395 6168,80,1987711 2317,92,6781954 3745,86,3873930 3138,87,3987535 3997,89,5085564 2396,89,5040529 3028,91,5904457 4015,95,9290301 4062,91,6434300 2771,84,3122397 427,99,19085038 2850,76,1342228 72,792 2805,61 2805,274
```

Is this simple to do?

Comment: Yes, it is simple to do.

Comment: If something is easy is a question of the perspective.